# Multiple Columns in one column

Tags: sql, view, h2

I have a Database which manages my music library, where I store all the id3 Tags in DB tables.    The data model looks as followed: http://abload.de/img/modelq5sx3.png

```
CREATE TABLE Tracks (
    Track_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Title VARCHAR(255),
    Track_Year YEAR,
    Filename VARCHAR(255),
    Track_Length CHAR(5),
    Folder_ID INTEGER,
    Album_ID INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tracks PRIMARY KEY (Track_ID),
    UNIQUE Unique_Path (Folder_ID, Filename)
);

CREATE TABLE Artists (
    Artist_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Artist VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Artists PRIMARY KEY (Artist_ID),
    UNIQUE (Artist)
);

CREATE TABLE Albums (
    Album_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Album VARCHAR(100),
    AlbumArtist INTEGER,
    AlbumCover VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Albums PRIMARY KEY (Album_ID),
    UNIQUE (Album)
);

CREATE TABLE Tracks_Artists (
    Artist_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Track_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tracks_Artists PRIMARY KEY (Artist_ID, Track_ID)
);
```

So I have tracks,albums and artists in seperate entities with a n:m relation between tracks and artists as a track can be performed by more than one artist and a artist can perform in more than one track. I have done that to search for tracks by artist.
But to make a nice track view I want to have all these artists in one line per track, which I did not manage so far. All I can do is to join over Album, which has one album artist per album:

```
create or replace view v_c_tracks as SELECT t.traCK_ID,t.title,ar.arTIST,a.album 
FROM TRACKS t 
join albums a on t.album_id=a.album_id
join artists ar on a.albumartist=ar.artist_id 
order by t.title;
```

Comment: Which database are you using (mysql, postgres, etc)? Also, please don't post links to images of schema: post the schema formatted as code

Comment: i use H2 a java based DB. I should post the sql create table statements? If you refer to the picture feature, I can not use it, since i need a reputation score of 10.

Comment: Post post the image either. Just copy paste the create statements into your question as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to the `track_artists` table.  Then to get the results on a single row, you need to aggregate by track.  The key to bringing the artists together in a list is `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT t.traCK_ID, t.title, group_concat(ar.artist) as artists, a.album 
FROM tracks t join
     albums a
     on t.album_id = a.album_id join
     track_artists ta
     on ta.track_id = track.track_id join
     artists ar
     on ta.artist_id = ar.artist_id 
group by t.traCK_ID, t.title, a.album
order by t.title;
```

Comment: thank you very much, thats all I needed! group_concat is nice